# my observable not returning data inspite of getting it from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, angular, express, observable

I am new to angular and node. Just completed the tutorial given in angular quickstart 'Tour of Heroes'. This works perfectly. But instead of using in memory web api as in the tutorial I want to modify it to get data from mongo db. So I modified my hero.service.ts to get the data from mongodb/express. But I get no data at all. And no error as well. I am stuck here. Would appreciate any help.

This is the function getHeroes from hero.service.ts.

```
getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
            return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
                       .map(response => response.json().data as Hero)
                       .catch((error : Response | any) => {
                             return Observable.throw(error.statusText);
                        });
}
```

In the dashboard component I subscribe to it as follows:

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Hero[] = [];

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

   ngOnInit(): void {
     this.heroService.getHeroes()
     .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(1, 5));
     // console.log("angular heroes",this.heroes );
   }
  }
```

Also here I get a typeerror for slice saying it cannot slice an undefined. but if I make it this.heroes.slice(1,5) it does not give error.

On the server side I have heroes.js. Here I get the data from mongo db which works fine.I can see that it has retrieved the list of heroes from database.

```
//Get All Heroes
 router.get('/heroes', function(req,res,next){
          db.heroes.find(function(err,heroes){
          if(err){
              res.send(err);
          }
          console.log("heroes:" , heroes);
          res.json(heroes);
         });
 });
```

08/08/2017:
 I modified my observable code as follows:

```
    getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
             return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
             .map(response => {
                  console.log('heroes',response.json());
                   response.json() as Hero[];
     })
     .catch((error : Response | any) => {
             return Observable.throw(error.statusText);
      });
    }
```

I removed response.json().data (because it was giving undefined in console.log,any idea why?) and made it response.json(). Now it shows me the heroes in console. But it does not make it till the subscription.

Comment: Try this .map(response => response.json().data as Hero[]) in your service

Comment: Seems like you are trying to cast an array of heroes to a hero.

Comment: How do you know you are not getting the data?

Comment: tried the change you suggested i.e.  .map(response => response.json().data as Hero[]) . But no change,still does not display anything.

Comment: II am not getting data because when I go to  my localhost:4200/ it displays only the html and not the heroes.I know I get it from databse because I did a console log output in heroes.js. So I know it is getting data from Database.

Comment: Please check the changes I made and results .I have put it at the end of the original post.